# Not able to connect with Auth0 in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, auth0

I am new to `Auth0` and trying to set up a login widget in `next.js` which provides the `access_token` and `id_token` for the signed-in user. I am kind of stuck and can't see the login widget anymore.

What I have implemented so far

In `_app.tsx`

```
import { UserProvider, useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Auth0Provider
        domain='mydomain.eu.auth0.com'
        clientId='my-client-secret'
      >
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Auth0Provider>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

In `index.tsx`

```
import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Home() {
  const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser();
  const router = useRouter();

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch('/api/auth/logout');
      router.push('/');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to log out', err);
    }
  };

  if (user) {
    console.log('idToken:', user.idToken);
    console.log('accessToken:', user.accessToken);

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Welcome, {user.name}</p>
        <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <a href="/api/auth/login">Login</a>;
  }
}
```

Whenever I am opening the application on the browser I am getting `404` for GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/me 404 (Not Found)

What am I doing wrong here? I couldn't find the official documentation for `Auth0` in `next.js` through which I can get the `access_token` and `id_token`. However, they do have something for `reactjs` but unfortunately, I am using `next.js`

Answer (score 2):

First for Auth0 Configuration, configure the following URLs for your application under the "Application URIs" section of the "Settings" page:

```
Allowed Callback URLs: http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback
Allowed Logout URLs: http://localhost:3000/
```

Create .env file with these values:

```
# A long, secret value used to encrypt the session cookie
AUTH0_SECRET='LONG_RANDOM_VALUE'
# The base url of your application
AUTH0_BASE_URL='http://localhost:3000'
# The url of your Auth0 tenant domain
AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL='https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN.auth0.com'
# Your Auth0 application's Client ID
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID='YOUR_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID'
# Your Auth0 application's Client Secret
AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET='YOUR_AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET'
```

If you are using **Next.js < 13** with /pages folder:

```
Create an auth directory under the /pages/api/ directory.
Create a [auth0].js file under the newly created auth directory.
```

The path to your dynamic API route file would be /pages/api/auth/[auth0].js.
Add to that file:

```
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default handleAuth();
```

As in the doc of nextjs-auth0:
Executing handleAuth() creates the following route handlers under the hood that perform different parts of the authentication flow:

```
/api/auth/login: Your Next.js application redirects users to your identity provider for them to log in (you can optionally pass a returnTo parameter to return to a custom relative URL after login, for example /api/auth/login?returnTo=/profile).
/api/auth/callback: Your identity provider redirects users to this route after they successfully log in.
/api/auth/logout: Your Next.js application logs out the user.
/api/auth/me: You can fetch user profile information in JSON format.
```

Wrap your pages/_app.js component with the UserProvider component:

```
// pages/_app.js
import React from 'react';
import { UserProvider } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

Consume Authentication:

```
// pages/index.js
import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';

export default function Index() {
  const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser();

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;

  if (user) {
    return (
      <div>
        Welcome {user.name}! <a href="/api/auth/logout">Logout</a>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <a href="/api/auth/login">Login</a>;
}
```

If you are using **Next.js >= 13** with App Router:

```
Create an api directory under the /app/ directory.
Create an auth directory under the newly created /app/api/ directory.
Create a [auth0] directory under the newly created auth directory.
Create a route.js file under the newly created [auth0] directory.
```

The path to your dynamic API route file will be /app/api/auth/[auth0]/route.js.

Add to that file:

```
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export const GET = handleAuth();
```

Wrap your app/layout.js component with the UserProvider component:

```
// app/layout.js
import React from 'react';
import { UserProvider } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';

export default function App({ children }) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

Consume Authentication:

```
// pages/index.js
'use client';
import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';

export default function Index() {
  const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser();

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;

  if (user) {
    return (
      <div>
        Welcome {user.name}! <a href="/api/auth/logout">Logout</a>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <a href="/api/auth/login">Login</a>;
}
```

Comment: How would we get the access token using your App Router method? Always getting a TypeError: "secret" is required warning but it's set and set properly. I can console it in my route file and see it.

Comment: @BlakeHayes You should check `AUTH0_SECRET`. This is a long secret value used to encrypt the session cookie. You can generate a suitable string using `openssl rand -hex 32` on the command line.
This conversation might help you with your issue: https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/issues/393